# Android draw TextView from CustomView

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, draw

I have a customview looking like this:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    protected Context c;
    protected String text;
    ... // and some more useful member variables...

    public CustomView(String text, Context c, ...) {

         this.text = text; this.c = c;
         ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(c);
        TextView tv = new TextView(c);
        tv.setText(text);
        ll.addView(tv);

        ll.draw(canvas);
    }
```

And in my main activity, I do this:

```
    RelativeLayout gamelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamelayout);

    CustomView customview = new CustomView("Textview text", this);
    gamelayout.addView(customview);
```

My problem is, that simply nothing is drawn, the drawn TextView does not appear in the "gamelayout". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not attaching the textview to any parent who is actually displayed on the screen !
And I'm not sure what are you trying to do here

Comment: Thats what I want to do by gamelayout.addView(customview).
This will invoke the onDraw method of the custom view, at least as far as I know. The gamelayout is displayed on the screen.

Comment: you can try this.addView(ll); ... to attach ll to gameLayout before calling ll.draw(canvas);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextView objects are not able to draw directly to the canvas, as you've done you need to assign to a Layout and then do this:

```
ll.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()); //Modify values as needed
```

Personally, I'm surprised there aren't errors thrown for calling `ll.draw()`. Unless you have a need to drawing a TextView I prefer drawing the text to the canvas:

```
canvas.drawText(...)
```

[See documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

Comment: Unfortunately, after adding this line, still nothing is drawn :(.
Whad exactly does canvas.getWidth() return? Any other suggestions?

Comment: canvas.getWidth() should return the width of the drawing canvas you're using. If you debug and check the value you should be getting something > 0

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinearLayout` isn't attached to your view

try `this.addView(ll)` to add your LinearLayout to your view.

Comment: You cannot add a `View Group` such as `Linear Layout` to View. You require a `View Group` for that.